# How to understand omniscience and omnipotence in order both can go side by side?

Tags: omniscience, omnipotence

My question is based on what I know from this [link](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/are-omniscience-and-omnipotence-mutually-inconsistent) where the question is

> Are omniscience and omnipotence mutually inconsistent?

And in the link there is The God Delusion by Richard Dawkins, where in short :

> If God is omniscient then He is not omnipotent.

To be honest I agree with Richard's conclusion above IF I use the understanding of omniscience and omnipotent like this :

- A. Omniscience = know all things happen absolutely
- B. Omnipotent = a power to do anything if desired

Since (to me) if the understanding is like A and B then A and B cannot go side by side ....so, how to understand Omniscience and Omnipotent (which is not like A and B) in order Omniscience and Omnipotent can go side by side ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are assuming that omnipotence = "changing the story". But that's a fallacy.

Comment: Infinity + Eternity = Being

Comment: @Conifold, thank you for the link. It's almost similar question of mine. Where in my own conclusion, the answer of the question from the link is : _"yes, omniscience and omnipotence mutually inconsistent IF (point A and B in my question)"_

Comment: Your A and B are too vague to say anything definitive. But  they are compatible when stated less naively.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you understand 'omniscience' and 'omnipotence':

> 'God is omniscient.' I shall take this to mean that God knows everything
>    which logically can be known.
>
> 'God is omnipotent.' I shall take this to mean that God can produce, alter,
>    or destroy everything that is logically capable of being produced, altered, or
>    destroyed. This amounts to saying that God can create any world that is
>    logically capable of being created. (R. W. K. Paterson, 'Evil, Omniscience and Omnipotence', Religious Studies, Vol. 15, No. 1 (Mar., 1979), pp. 1-23: 2.)

There is plainly no *prima facie* incompatibility between omniscience and omnipotence if this is what we take the concepts to mean. How might incompatibility arise ? If God knows that X will happen at time t1 by virtue of Godself's omniscience, then God has no power to prevent X from happening at t1 despite Godself's omnipotence. That generates a conflict between omniscience and omnipotence.

But there is a way round this. Omnipotence is limited to the logically possible. If God knows that X will happen at t1, then in the following sense it is logically impossible for X not to happen: it is logically impossible for God to know what is false but if by virtue of Godself's omnipotence, X could be prevented from happening at t1, God's knowledge that X will happen at t1 would be false: and false knowledge is logically impossible.